# Need to create dictionary of idf values, associating words with their idf values

Tags: tfidfvectorizer

I understand how to get the idf values and vocabulary using the vectorizer. With vocabulary the frequency of the word is the value and the word is the key of a dictionary, however, what I want the value to be is the idf value.

I haven't been able to try anything because I don't know how to work with sklearn.

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
# list of text documents
text = ["The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.",
        "The dog.",
        "The fox"]
# create the transform
vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer()
# tokenize and build vocab
vectorizer.fit(text)
# summarize
print(vectorizer.vocabulary_)
print(vectorizer.idf_)
# encode document
vector = vectorizer.transform([text[0]])
# summarize encoded vector
print(vector.shape)
print(vector.toarray())
```

The code provided above is what I was originally trying to work with.

I have since come up with a new solution that does not use scikit:

```
            for string in text_array: 
                for word in string:
                    if word not in total_dict.keys(): # build up a word frequency in the dictionary
                        total_dict[word] = 1
                    else:
                        total_dict[word] += 1
            for word in total_dict.keys(): # calculate the tf-idf of each word in the dictionary using this url: https://nlpforhackers.io/tf-idf/
                total_dict[word] = math.log(len(text_array) / float(1 + total_dict[word]))
                print("word", word, ":" , total_dict[word])
```

Let me know if the code snippet above is enough to allow a reasonable estimation of what is going on. I included a link to what I was using for guidance.

Answer (score 0):

You can directly use `vectorizer.fit_transform(text)` for the first time.
What it does is build a vocabulary set according to all the word/tokens in the text.

And then you can use `vectorizer.transform(anothertext)` to vectorize another text with the same mapping as the previous text.

**More explanation:**

`fit()` is to learn vocabulary and idf from training set. `transform()` is to transform the documents based on the learned vocabulary from the previous `fit()`.

So you should only do `fit()` once, and can transform many times.

Comment: Thank you for your response! This is my first time on stackoverflow so I hope I'm not doing too poorly. Is there any way you could show me in a bit more detail? I've never done this before. New to this library and to data science all together. 

So, when you say ```vectorizer.fit_transform(text)``` I just replace ```vectorizer.fit(text)``` with it? Can I ask what they are doing with this line, ```vector = vectorizer.transform([text[0]])```?

Comment: So it sounds to me like transform turns a dictionary into an array, if that's right then I don't need it. Right? Because my goal is to have a dictionary where the keys are the words and their values are their idf scores. Or am I misunderstanding transform?

Comment: If you only need the vocabulary set, then you dont need transform.

Comment: Sorry but I don't think I'm being clear enough. Vocabulary set only provides the vocabulary, right? I'm looking for a data structure that couples the vocabulary with the idf.

Comment: Also I updated the original post with some additional code if that helps you at all, thanks again!